# Getting AttributeError: 'TestRoutes' object has no attribute 'app'

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

Code below is unit test I'm writing for a flask app but results in the following error when I run the test:

```
  File "/Users/ausername/projects/term_trader/tt2/tests/testRoutes.py", line 47, in test_deposit_route
    response = self.app.post(BASE_URL,
AttributeError: 'TestRoutes' object has no attribute 'app'
```

Imports look okay to me as I had some other tests running out of a 'tests' folder with no issue. The routes themselves work just fine when I tested them in curl, I'm just trying to get in the habit of writing tests. Just can't seem to figure out what the issue is. This is flask version 1.0.3. Any advise is appreciated.

Code:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from model.user import User
from model.position import Position
from model.trade import Trade
from flask_app.app import app
from schema import build_user, build_positions, build_trades
import json
import os


BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/'


class TestRoutes(TestCase):

    def setup(self):
        self.app.config['TESTING'] = True
        self.app.config['DEBUG'] = False
        self.app = app.test_client()

        build_user()
        build_positions()
        build_trades()

        bob = User(**{
        "user_name": "bobdean",
        "password": "password",
        "real_name": "Bob Dean",
        "balance": 0.0
        })
        bob.hash_password("password")
        bob.api_key = "11111111111111111111"
        bob.save()

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_deposit_route(self):
        bob = User.from_pk(1)
        self.assertEqual(mike.user_name, "bobdean")
        deposit = {"amount":1500.0}
        response = self.app.post(BASE_URL,
                                 data=json.dumps(deposit),
                                 content_type='application/json')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201, "Status Code should be 201")
        self.assertEqual(bob.balance, 1500.0, "Bob's balance should equal 1500")
```

Comment: Well, where do you think `self.app` is defined? Note that your setup method is not being called; it should be called `setUp` to be run automatically; but when you fix that, you'll get the same error in that method.

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/

Comment: @DanielRoseman, correct I did have to cleanup a few other oddities this but setUp pointed me in the right direction, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rename setup to setUp according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp)

Comment: Yup knew it was something small.

Comment: took me two hours to realise this. this worked for me